# Prove that $E$ is self adjoint iff $EE^*=E^*E$ where $E$ is a projection .

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, projection

I dont want the rigorous proof but I want the geometric intuition of the statement.

Now I know if $E$ is a projection operator (where $V$ is given to be finite dimensional) then $$V = R(E) \bigoplus K(E)$$

Since, it is a self adjoint operator so I am also aware of the fact that there exists an orthonormal basis of eigen vectors of $E$ but then I cant really find the geometric intuition of $EE^*=E^*E$.

Comment: $E$ self adjoint means $E=E^*$, so your identity is $E^2=E^2$. Could you please clarify your point?

Comment: This is a question from Hoffman and Kunze pg-299 8.4-11

Comment: if you want to prove this without spectral theorem see:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021347/if-pp-pp-and-p2-p-then-show-that-p-p/  .   This may not help with geometric intuition per se