# Why is $\phi$ diagonalizable if $\phi \circ \phi =id_V$?

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

V is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$- vector space with $\phi: V \rightarrow V$

Why does it follow that $\phi$ is diagonalizable if $\phi \circ \phi = id_{V}$?

My ideas so far:

I do know that if i can show that the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the dimensions of the matrix that it therefore has to be diagonalizable, as well as that if i can show that there exists an invertable matrix M that results in this $M^{-1}*\phi*M$ being diagonal then $\phi$ has to be diagonalizable.
I also think there was a way to go about this by showing that there is a Basis of V taht consists of eigenvectors but im not sure about how that works.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @MichaelBurr ill edit it in

Comment: Do you want to assume $V$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani yes.

Comment: Do you have the Jordan canonical form available? It's  easy to see that the only Jordan blocks that square to an identity block are a single $-1$ or $1$.

Comment: for a very simple proof that does not require minimal polynomials:  confirm that $\frac{1}{2}(\phi +I)$ is idempotent and hence diagonalizable, ref the optional post-script here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021347/if-pp-pp-and-p2-p-then-show-that-p-p/4021435#4021435 (note: this implies your involution is diagonalizable over any field that isn't characteristic 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the characteristic of the field (such as $\mathbb Q$) is not $2$. Here is a simple way to see it. As has been noted, all the eigenvalues are either $1$ or $-1$. Let $V_+$ be the subspace of $V$ spanned by eigenvectors of eigenvalue $1$, and $V_-$ be similarly defined (a priori, $V_{\pm}$ could be $\{0\}$). One now proceeds to show that $$V=V_+\oplus V_-.$$ If $v\in V_+\cap V_-$, then $\phi(v)=v=-v,$ hence $v= 0$. This shows that $$V_+\cap V_-=\{0\}.\qquad (1)$$ For any vector $v\in V$, consider $$v_+:=v+\phi(v)~{\rm and ~}v_-:=v-\phi(v).\qquad (2)$$ One has $$\phi(v_+)=\phi(v+\phi(v))=\phi(v)+\phi^2(v)=v+\phi(v)=v_+\in V_+$$and $$\phi(v_-)=\phi(v-\phi(v))=\phi(v)-\phi^2(v)=-(v-\phi(v))=-v_-\in V_-.$$ It then follows from (2) that $v=\frac 1 2(v_++v_-)\in V_++V_-$, hence from (1), one gets a direct sum $$V=V_+\oplus V_-.$$ Since there is a basis consisting of eigenvectors, $\phi$ can be diagonaized.

Answer (score 0):

We have\begin{align}
\phi\circ\phi & = id_V\\
\phi\circ\phi - id_V & = 0\\
(\phi + id_V)(\phi - id_V) & = 0,\\
\end{align}
so the minimal polynomial for $\phi$ divides $(x + 1)(x - 1)$. Have you learned yet how to characterize a diagonalizable linear operator by its minimal polynomial? Look for such a theorem in your textbook.

Comment: so that would mean that the eigenvalues would be +1 and -1, im not sure how this proves that $\phi$ is diagonalizable tho

Comment: @AnotherNoone: If $\phi$ satisfies a polynomial which can be written as a product of distinct linear factors, then $\phi$ is diagonalisable.

Comment: $(x+1)(x-1)$ is not necessarily the _minimal_ polynomial -- for all we know, $\phi$ could be $I$ or $-I$.