# Artin's Algebra problem no-9 in Miscellaneous part of chapter 4

Tags: linear-algebra

Q. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. A linear operator $T: V \rightarrow V$ is called a projection if $T^{2}=T$ (not necessarily an "orthogonal projection"). Let ${K}$ and $W$ be the kernel and image of a linear operator $T$. Prove

(a) $T$ is a projection onto $W$ if and only if the restriction of $T$ to $W$ is the identity map.

(b) If $T$ is a projection, then $V$ is the direct sum $W \oplus K$.

(c) The trace of a projection $T$ is equal to its rank.

I didn't find this question in old posts.

My approach:-

(a).

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. And let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator. Let $K=K e r(T)$ and $W=i m(T)$.
Suppose $T^{2}=T$. Then for any $v \in V$ we have $T^{2} v=T v$ i.e. $T(T(v))=T(v)$. That's for each $w \in W$ we have $T(w)=w$.
Conversely suppose, $T(w)=w, \forall w \in W$. Choose $v \in V$. Then $T(v) \in W$. So that $T(T(v))=T(v)$ i.e. $T^{2}(v)=T$

(b).

Suppose $T^{2}=T$. Then for any $v \in V$ we have $v=T v+(v-T v)$. Also, $T(v-T v)=T v-T(T(v))=$ $T v-T v=0$ i.e. $V=W+K$.

Now suppose $u \in W \cap K$, then $u \in W$ i.e. $u=T\left(u^{\prime}\right)$ for some $u^{\prime} \in V$. And $u \in K$ implies $T u=0$. Now $0=T u=T\left(T\left(u^{\prime}\right)\right)=T^{2}\left(u^{\prime}\right)=T\left(u^{\prime}\right)=u$. Hence $W \cap K=\{0\}$. So that $V=W \oplus K$.

Here is my approach for (a). And (b). Please cheak this and also you can give alternative solution. And please give me hints and solution for (c). Thank you

Comment: note that 3 isn't quite true for fields of positive characteristic (you get the rank mod $p$ in such a case). I gave a proof that trace gives rank (using material only covered in the first 4 chapters of 1st edition of Arin) here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021347/if-pp-pp-and-p2-p-then-show-that-p-p/4021435#4021435 under "optional post-script"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(c) follows from (a) and (b) directly. Take a basis $\mathcal{B}_1=\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ of $W$ and a basis $\mathcal{B}_2=\{k_{m+1},\dots,k_n\}$ of $K$. (b) says $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}_1\cup \mathcal{B}_2$ is a basis of $V$. By (a) and the definition of $K$, one has $T(w_i)=w_i$ for $1\le i\le m$ and $T(k_j)=0$ for $m+1\le j\le n$. Thus the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. $\mathcal{B}$ has the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}I_m&0\\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
It is clear that $\mathrm{Tr}(T)=m=\mathrm{rank}(T)=\dim(W).$