An exercise about singular value decomposition
I am working on an exercise about singular value decomposition:

Suppose that $A$ is an invertible matrix with singular value decomposition
$$
A=\sum_{i=1}^ns_iu_iv_i^T
$$
where $u_i$ is the left singular vectors (orthonormal eigenvectors of $AA^T$) and $v_i$ is the right singular vectors. Show that
$$
A^{-1}=\sum_{i=1}s_i^{-1}v_iu_i^T
$$

My idea is to check that
$$
AA^{-1}=I_n
$$
However, I got
$$
AA^{-1}=\sum_{i=1}^n u_iu_i^T
$$
Is it equal to $I_n$?

What is $\text{trace}\big(\sum_{i=1}^n u_iu_i^T\big)$ and what is $\big(\sum_{i=1}^n u_iu_i^T\big)^2$?  (Note: you implicitly already computed the latter-- consider the special case of $v_i = u_i$ and $s_i=1$).

@user8675309 I know that the eigenvalue of $I_n$ is $1$. But why the eigenvectors of $I$ are still $u_i$ for $i=1,\dots, n$? If so, we will have $I_n=\sum u_iu_i^T$?

Look I gave you 2 very simple questions that lead immediately to a solution since the only $n\times n$ idempotent matrix with trace $n$ is the identity matrix.  If you ignore them the only other hint I will give is $A^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $A$ [whereas $-A$ would be the additive inverse] so instead of writing $A$ as a sum of rank 1 matrices, convert that into a product of 3 matrices.

@user8675309 Yes, it is clear if we convert them into a product of three matrices that we have $A=USV^T$, then $A^{-1}=VSU^T$...

@user8675309 Can we prove your statement"since the only × idempotent matrix with trace  is the identity matrix"?

see the "optional post-script" here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021347/if-pp-pp-and-p2-p-then-show-that-p-p/4021435#4021435 for a very basic general proof of the trace claim.  However in your case you are dealing with a real symmetric idempotent matrix which could allow for short-cuts.

Note that for any $x$ we have $x = \sum_k v_k v_k^T x$, (note that this shows that $\sum_k v_k v_k^T = I $) since the $v_k$ are an orthonormal basis.
To compute $A^{-1}$ we solve $Ax=y$ for $x$.
If $\sum_k s_k u_k v_k^T x = y $, then premultiplying by $u_i$ gives
$s_i v_i^T x = u_i^T y$, or $v_i ^T x = {1 \over s_i} u_i^T y$.
Hence $x = \sum_k v_k v_k^T x = \sum_i {1 \over s_i} v_i u_i^T y$ from which we get $A^{-1} = \sum_i {1 \over s_i} v_i u_i^T$.
